# Is there any problem if I set and use a single font ( Arial ) in my entire web site?

Tags: html, css, fonts

From my previous experience in web design, I noticed that web pages' text is set to use many alternative fonts.
Is it allowed to set a single font ( Arial ) to the entire web site, like in this case (style="font-family:arial")?

Comment: The rules for font-family are pretty clear and easily looked up on the web: if you specify font-family at all (and you absolutely don't have to), then its value should be one or more text values (with a value surrounded in quotes, if there are special characters in that value), separated by commas if there's more than one.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but not every system has Arial.

It's best to set a couple fallback fonts, or at least `sans-serif` or you may get stuck with a font that looks particularly bad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use only one font for your entire site but from UI/UX designer perspective, limit the system to only one font will probably make the site look boring, hard to navigate and lack of [contrast](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I got it right. But using a lot of different fonts on a singe webpage can make it look awfull and weird, but using only a single one will make the reader get bored.
Try using it wisely, not more than 3 or 4 different fonts. You may want to call your reader attention.

If you are looking for problems during the navigation, try using emmbed fonts, like Google Fonts.